# JScrollpane: scroll only by unitIncrement

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I created JPanel with implemented `Scrollable` interface and overrided method `getScrollableBlockIncrement`.
I placed JPanel into JScrollPane.
And JPanel contains several components with same height. This height is the unitIncrement.
Now, when I click on arrow on the vertical scrollbar, viewport moves by unitIncrement.
But, when I move knob with mouse, viewport moves by pixels.
How to make viewport to move only by unitIncrement?

Update: 
Knob is the middle button on scrollbar, on track, to drag it. As shown there [How a Scroll Pane Works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#operation)

I want viewport moves only by unitIncrement in any way. Also when I press left mouse button on knob and drag it. The example behaviour: intellisense in Eclipse.

Update 2: 
I tried 
`myJScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);`
And didn't get desired behaviour. 
When I debugged code, I found that parameter unitIncrement is discarded when I drag the knob.

Update 3: 
Couldn't find suitable solution with JScrollPane and wrote custom scroll pane.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make JScrollPane scroll 1 line per mouse wheel step?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397581/how-to-make-jscrollpane-scroll-1-line-per-mouse-wheel-step)

Comment: See also [*Implementing a Scrolling-Savvy Client*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable).

Comment: Does _knob with mouse_ mean [scroll wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_wheel)?

Comment: Lukas Knuth, useful link, thanks. But this is not duplicate.

Comment: Trashgod, I read this and didn't find solution there. See update.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question could be found with a little search effort:  [How do I speed up the scroll speed in a JScrollPane when using the mouse wheel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583495/how-do-i-speed-up-the-scroll-speed-in-a-jscrollpane-when-using-the-mouse-wheel)

To reiterate, you basically want to modify the `JScrollBar` on your `JScollPane`.

```
myJScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
```

Otherwise, you're left with overriding the Scolling event on the JScrollPane to pass in the amount you want to scroll based on the pane that's being scrolled - that's a little messy... so if the first way works for you, that's what I'd go with.

Bottom line: the problem's with `JScollPane` - not your `Scrollable` class.