# JScrollPane step size when dragging

Tags: java, swing, mouse, jscrollpane, drag

Is it possible to specify the step size of a JScrollPane when dragging it?

I'm aware of `setUnitIncrement` and `setBlockIncrement`, but these do not work when dragging the scrollbar.

**Edit: AdjustmentListener**

```
final AdjustmentListener myAdjustmentListener = new AdjustmentListener() {
   @Override
   public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
       if (e.getAdjustmentType() == AdjustmentEvent.TRACK){
           e.getAdjustable().setUnitIncrement(500);
           e.getAdjustable().setBlockIncrement(500);
       }
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `setUnitIncrement` and `setBlockIncrement` values only changes the scroll speed when scrolling with a mouse wheel, the arrow keys, and the scroll bar arrows. These values do not change the scroll speed when the scroll bars are dragged.

However the `AdjustmentListener` can be added to a scrollbar to listen to the scrollbar movements.

Comment: yes this is controled by proportional value Rectangle from JViewport v.s. JComponent in JScrollPane

Comment: I edited my answer and added the AdjustmentListener I'm currently using. Which event should I use to listen for scrollbar movements?

Answer (score 0):

An AdjustmentListener should do the magic for you. Did you look at this:
[How to make JScrollPane scroll 1 line per mouse wheel step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397581/how-to-make-jscrollpane-scroll-1-line-per-mouse-wheel-step)

Comment: Yes, my running ``AdjustmentListener`` is derived from that. I've edited my original post and added the current version of the listener. But it only covers mouse-wheel scrolling and scroll bar arrows, not dragging of the bar itself.